# Error when loading scripts in Wordpress admin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using Wordpress Images Gallery and each time I try to add new images I get this error in the console:

> GET ...
>   wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sorta&load%5B%5D=ble,thickbox,underscore,shortcode,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload&ver=4.9.8
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Everything worked perfectly until recently and I really don't know what could be the cause. I do not have a lot of experience using Wordpress, so I am not sure what other information could be relevant. Also, the error seems kind of vague to me. I will provide further details if required.

I suspect there are too many scripts to load and that gives the error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled script concatenation in config and everything works. Thanks.